# Как поместить исходный код в Jar файл

Tags: java

Не могу понять как мне поместить исходный код Java в Jar файл. Использую IntellijIdea

Comment: Не нужно исходный код помещать в jar файлы, в jar файлы помещаются скомпилированные в байткод классы. Это происходит при сборке проекта. Как конкретно - нужно смотреть как у вас настроена сборка - средствами IDE или средствами какой-то системы сборки (maven, gradle или других)

Comment: Хочу добавить, что не обязательны нужны системы сборки, её можно выполнить через javac